# How to prevent Eclipse from indenting textarea's content on Ctrl+Shift+F?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I'm using Eclipse (Juno). I have a form on a JSP page that has a textarea as follows:

```
<textarea name="t"><c:out value="${val}" /></textarea>
```

When I format the code (ctrl shift F) it becomes:

```
<textarea name="t">
    <c:out value="${val}" />
</textarea>
```

Which is fine except that it inserts extra spaces and lines in the text area. I like formatting my code using Eclipse, but the spaces/lines get added to the database when the form is submitted. Even worse, it gets compounded every time that form is submitted again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Formatting with Eclipse. Unless you can switch off formatting for that tag it will keep doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "textarea" to the list of inline elements on the Web->HTML Files->Editor preference page.

Comment: That did it. Now I need to remember to do this to every new installation of Eclipse on every machine. I am surprised that this issue has not come up with anyone before.

Comment: @stepanian It has, that's why there's a setting for it.

Comment: @DaveNewton What I meant was, if it is good practice to use c:out inside textareas and the default formatting in Eclipse added the spaces, then a lot of people would have complained about it causing the default Eclipse behavior to change.

Comment: @stepanian Most people wouldn't use c:out when there's JSP EL and skip the extra tag, although I don't know if that would fix the default formatting. Since it's easy to change, though, I'm not convinced the default behavior is that big a deal. File an issue against it and see what happens.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not a big deal. I will add it to the list of my custom settings for Eclipse so that I don't forget to make the change for each Eclipse installation. Otherwise, I could be changing something else on the page, press Ctrl+Shift+F and never know that I screwed up the functionality of the app :) Thanks for all your insight though.